# python element wise operation in function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In python, I am trying to change the values of np array inside the function

```
def function(array):
    array = array + 1
array = np.zeros((10, 1))
function(array)
```

For array as function parameter, it is supposed to be a reference, and I should be able to modify its content inside function.

array = array + 1 performs element wise operation that adds one to every element in the array, so it changes inside values.

But the array actually does not change after the function call. I am guessing that the program thinks I am trying to change the reference itself, not the content of the array, because of the syntax of the element wise operation. Is there any way to make it do the intended behavior? I don't want to loop through individual elements or make the function return the new array.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
array = array + 1
```

… does perform an elementwise operation, but the operation it performs is creating a new array with each element incremented. Assigning that array back to the local variable `array` doesn't do anything useful, because that local variable is about to go away, and you haven't done anything to change the global variable of the same name,

On the other hand, this line:

```
array += 1
```

… performs the elementwise operation of incrementing all of the elements in-place, which is probably what you want here.

---

In Python, mutable collections are only *allowed*, not *required*, to handle the `+=` statement this way; they *could* handle it the same way as `array = array + 1` (as immutable types like `str` do). But builtin types like `list`, and most popular third-party types like `np.array`, do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you want to change the content of your array is to use this:

```
array[:] = array + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# multi modification
import numpy as np
def func(array):
    array += 1
array = np.zeros((10, 1))
func(array)
print(array)

def preprocess_data(data)...
    modify_array(data['array_part'])


def modify_array(array):
    array += 1

def main():
    data = {
        'array_part': np.zeros((10, 1)) #....,
    }
    preprocess_data(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does this solution add that the other solutions (which are a few years old and still accurate) do not? Please include some explanation with your code.